# Open txt file in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

i need to open a txt file .
In txt file i have

```
Andrei:Popescu:Bucuresti
Maria:Popescu:Targu-Mures
....
```

How do I read a text file into three variable and for each line do something ?
Sorry for my english.

Comment: Treat it as a csv file with delimiter `:` Docs here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html

Comment: Or use `split`. Or locate the `:` manually ... etc. etc. So many ways.

Comment: And how i can turn this into three variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that the names are separated by a colon(`:`) so add `:` in `split()` to split them and store them in multiple variables:

```
    with open("filename.txt") as f:
        for line in f :
            word1,word2,word3 = line.split(":")

    print(word1)
    print(word2)
    print(word3)
```