# How to store a txt file in your program and reference it

Tags: python, pycharm, text-files

Let me preface by saying I am very new to programming. I'm creating a fun program that I can use to start my day at work. One of the things I want it to do is display a random compliment. I made a text file that has multiple lines in it. How do I store that text file then open it?

I've opened text files before that were on my desktop but I want this one to be embedded in the code so when I compile the program I can take it to any computer.

I've googled a ton of different key words and keep finding the basics of opening and reading txt files but that's not exactly what I need.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Open txt file in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41383214/open-txt-file-in-python)

Comment: You don't compile python, so if you're taking your *script* to another computer, you might as well take the txt file too. If you wanted it to be an "internal" file, you would create another class, with the text in a python `List`, but that will still likely be another file (unless you want to put it in the same file as your code)

Comment: Store the text as a variable in the code?

Comment: @zeet OP explicitly states that they know how to do that and that they don't want to do that. Not to mention, the linked question is terrible...

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps start with defining a default path to your file; this makes it easier to change the path when moving to another computer. Next, define a function in your program to read and return the contents of the file:

```
FILE_PATH = "my/path/to/file/"

def read_file(file_name):
    with open(FILE_PATH + file_name) as f:
        return f.read()
```

With that in place, you can use this function to read, modify, or display the file contents, for example to edit something from your file:

```
def edit_comments():
    text = read_file("daily_comments.txt")
    text = text.replace("foo", "foo2")
    return text
```

There are obviously many ways to approach this task, this is just a simple example to get you started.